# How to change primary network interface name on CentOS 6 hosted on AWS?

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services

I need to change the primary network interface name from eth0 to something like net0, what would be the best way to achieve this on CentOS 6 under AWS ?

I tried to change it via /etc/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules and cloud-init but I had no luck till now.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Br00TCn.gif

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Br00TCn.gif